# Is a github port 59249 request valid

Tags: networking, ssh, git, github

I'm on macOS Sierra and keep getting requests to allow port 59249. When I look at the request details, I see that it appears to come from github:

```
lb-192.30.253.124-iad.github.com
```

I am using github over ssh for development work. However, when I search for the [ports page on github](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.11/admin/guides/installation/network-ports-to-open/), I see no reference to this port number (this page is for Enterprise; doesn't seem to be a similar page for non-enterprise users).

Github does say that they are currently using IP addresses `192.30.252.0/22` so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Any insight would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, your firewall is just interpreting an *outgoing* connection backwards.

- All TCP connections have an address and port *on both ends*. When *you* connect to GitHub (on port 22 or 443 or such), the connection comes *from* a randomly selected port number, usually in the range 49152–65535 or 32768–65535 or such.

  For example, a SSH connection might be `192.168.1.x:59249 <--> 192.30.253.124:22`.
- The only difference between "incoming" and "outgoing" connections is the initial handshake. Once the connection gets established, everything becomes fully symmetric.

  So if you only start a firewall after the connection has been established, and the first thing it sees is a packet from `github:80` to `yourpc:59249`, it has no way of knowing whether the connection was originally incoming or outgoing.

  **Or** perhaps in your case it doesn't see outgoing "initiate connection" packets *at all*, but still sees the incoming responses, and *thinks* that it's GitHub who is initiating a connection towards you.

  This can certainly happen if you use both Ethernet and Wi-Fi at the same time: the handshake (TCP SYN) might be sent via Ethernet, but the response (SYN-ACK) might arrive via Wi-Fi; although that's quite valid, some firewalls mistakenly think they belong to different connections.

Comment: Yep; Norton Security got confused and probably, as you said, because of both Ethernet & WiFi going at the same time.Nice description; thanks!

Comment: Turns out, github uses ports starting 59249 for that initial handshake request -- so that's where it's coming from.

Comment: Really? GitHub cannot possibly choose your local port for _outgoing_ requests. Your OS chooses that.

Comment: @grawty... That's what GitHub told me when I inquired. Maybe they don't "set" it, but they certainly are the ones that are generating these requests because I was able to eventually track in down through the logs. And it's repeatable...